# How to get name for each argument in variadic macros?

Tags: c++, macros, c++14, c++17

It's possible to create a macro `str(a)` that will use its argument (`a`) and its stringified name (`#a`), for example:

```
#include <iostream>

#define str(a) #a, " ", a

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    float f = 4.5;
    const char* s = "string";

    auto l = [] (const auto&... p) { (std::cout << ... << p) << std::endl; };

    l(str(i));
    l(str(f));
    l(str(s));
}
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0461d5020cef3218).

Is there a simple way to print *variable* number of arguments prepended with a name of each argument? i.e. implement `PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG` from the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename ... Ts>
void print_all(const Ts&... ts)
{
    (std::cout << ... << ts) << std::endl;
}

#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG(...) // how to implement '#a, " ", a' here?
#define PRINT_ALL(...) print_all(PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG(__VA_ARGS__))

int main()
{
    auto a = 10;
    auto b = 20.1;
    auto c = "string";
    auto d = 'c';
    PRINT_ALL(a, b, c, d);
}
```

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a4a028de4d33b2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can use [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html), you can do this:

```
#define PROCESS_ONE_ELEMENT(r, unused, idx, elem) \
  BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(idx) BOOST_PP_STRINGIZE(elem) , " " , elem

#define PRINT_ALL(...) \
  print_all(BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(PROCESS_ONE_ELEMENT, %%, BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/98fe9702796e4f00)

I use `%%` as a placholder for "unused value."

Answer (score 7):

The [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.htmlhttp://) library is definitely a great solution. If, however, you do not want to be dependent on external libraries, you could something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

#define str(a) #a, " = ", a

#define VA_NUM_ARGS(...) VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL(__VA_ARGS__, 5,4,3,2,1)
#define VA_NUM_ARGS_IMPL(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,N,...) N

#define CONCAT_IMPL( x, y ) x##y
#define MACRO_CONCAT( x, y ) CONCAT_IMPL( x, y )

// to verify, run the preprocessor alone (g++ -E):
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_1(a) str(a)
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_2(a, ...) str(a) , " ; " , PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_3(a, ...) str(a) , " ; " , PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_2(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_4(a, ...) str(a) , " ; " , PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_3(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_5(a, ...) str(a) , " ; " , PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_4(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG(...) MACRO_CONCAT(PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_, VA_NUM_ARGS(__VA_ARGS__)) (__VA_ARGS__) 
#define PRINT_ALL(...) print_all(PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG(__VA_ARGS__))

template<typename T>
void print_impl(const T& t)
{
   std::cout << t;
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
void print_impl(const T& t, const Ts&... ts)
{
   std::cout << t;
   print_impl(ts...);
}


template <typename ... Ts>
void print_all(const Ts&... ts)
{
   print_impl(ts...);
   std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   auto a = 10;
   auto b = 20.1;
   auto c = "string";
   auto d = 'c';
   PRINT_ALL(a, b, c, d);
}
```

Here the idea is to count the number of arguments using `VA_NUM_ARGS` and use the result of that to call the correct `PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_#` macro, which will "recursively" call the next `PREPEND_EACH_ARG_WITH_HASH_ARG_#` for each argument in `__VA_ARGS__`.

The small drawback is that it is limited in the number of arguments it can take, but on the other hand this is easily extend-able.

Comment: IOW, re-implement that bit of Boost.Preprocessor yourself :-)

Comment: @Angew Yes more or less :) I wasn't sure how exactly the Boost library was implemented (it is probably a little more intelligent than my example). I usually like being independent of third party libraries, so I thought the solution worth to mention.

Comment: @Banan, thanks for the explanations, however accepted the reference to boost as answer because it is more "simple way" :)